# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Setup Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: sql-server, windows, unauthorized

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 Developer edition on my laptop which had it working previously. My laptop was running low on disk space and I had to uninstall it earlier. It no longer works and fails at the last moment giving me an unauthorized error. I used process monitor to look at the problem and can see that it is attempting to gain access to the registry key 
**"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\FltMgr"** but gets an **access denied**. I have tried several attempts to grant Full access to everyone on that registry key but it does not work. I have read several articles before posting it here and so please do not think that I have come here to get an answer quickly without proper investigation although I would love to get it sorted quickly. Any ideas please?

**OS: Windows 10 Home Edition**

Although the installation failed, I can see the windows service "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" which does not start. The following error is shown in the event viewer.
**initerrlog: Could not open error log file ''. Operating system error = 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).**

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Failed: see details below
  Exit code (Decimal):           -2068119551
  Start time:                    2016-11-14 14:55:15
  End time:                      2016-11-14 15:24:10
  Requested action:              Install

Setup completed with required actions for features.
Troubleshooting information for those features:
  Next step for SQLEngine:       Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Next step for Replication:     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.


Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  DESKTOP-9VOUAM4
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Future Windows Version
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2012 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2012
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       11
  Installation location:         D:\sqlserver\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Developer

  Slipstream:                    True
  SP Level                       2

Product Update Status:
  Success: KB 2958429

Product Updates Selected for Installation:
  Title:                         Service Pack 2
  Knowledge Based Article:       KB 2958429
  Version:                       11.2.5058.0
  Architecture:                  x64
  Language:                      1033

  Update Source:                 Slipstream


User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        Install
  ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN:      false
  AGTSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT
  AGTSVCPASSWORD:                *****
  AGTSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Manual
  ASBACKUPDIR:                   Backup
  ASCOLLATION:                   Latin1_General_CI_AS
  ASCONFIGDIR:                   Config
  ASDATADIR:                     Data
  ASLOGDIR:                      Log
  ASPROVIDERMSOLAP:              1
  ASSERVERMODE:                  MULTIDIMENSIONAL
  ASSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  ASSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ASSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  ASSYSADMINACCOUNTS:            <empty>
  ASTEMPDIR:                     Temp
  BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE:         Disabled
  CLTCTLRNAME:                   <empty>
  CLTRESULTDIR:                  <empty>
  CLTSTARTUPTYPE:                0
  CLTSVCACCOUNT:                 <empty>
  CLTSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  CLTWORKINGDIR:                 <empty>
  COMMFABRICENCRYPTION:          0
  COMMFABRICNETWORKLEVEL:        0
  COMMFABRICPORT:                0
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161114_145357\ConfigurationFile.ini
  CTLRSTARTUPTYPE:               0
  CTLRSVCACCOUNT:                <empty>
  CTLRSVCPASSWORD:               <empty>
  CTLRUSERS:                     <empty>
  ENABLERANU:                    false
  ENU:                           true
  ERRORREPORTING:                false
  FEATURES:                      SQLENGINE, REPLICATION, SSMS, ADV_SSMS
  FILESTREAMLEVEL:               0
  FILESTREAMSHARENAME:           <empty>
  FTSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  FTSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTALLSHAREDDIR:              C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSHAREDWOWDIR:           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTALLSQLDATADIR:             <empty>
  INSTANCEDIR:                   d:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\
  INSTANCEID:                    MSSQLSERVER
  INSTANCENAME:                  MSSQLSERVER
  ISSVCACCOUNT:                  NT AUTHORITY\Network Service
  ISSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  ISSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  MATRIXCMBRICKCOMMPORT:         0
  MATRIXCMSERVERNAME:            <empty>
  MATRIXNAME:                    <empty>
  NPENABLED:                     0
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  ROLE:                          <empty>
  RSINSTALLMODE:                 DefaultNativeMode
  RSSHPINSTALLMODE:              DefaultSharePointMode
  RSSVCACCOUNT:                  <empty>
  RSSVCPASSWORD:                 <empty>
  RSSVCSTARTUPTYPE:              Automatic
  SAPWD:                         *****
  SECURITYMODE:                  SQL
  SQLBACKUPDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLCOLLATION:                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
  SQLSVCACCOUNT:                 NT Service\MSSQLSERVER
  SQLSVCPASSWORD:                <empty>
  SQLSVCSTARTUPTYPE:             Automatic
  SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS:           BUILTIN\Administrators
  SQLTEMPDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLTEMPDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQLUSERDBDIR:                  <empty>
  SQLUSERDBLOGDIR:               <empty>
  SQMREPORTING:                  false
  TCPENABLED:                    0
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  UpdateEnabled:                 true
  UpdateSource:                  Slipstream
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161114_145357\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Management Tools - Complete
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Management Tools - Basic
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84BB0001
  Error description:             Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.5058.0&EvtType=0x48BB60BC%400xBB814387&EvtType=0x48BB60BC%400xBB814387

  Feature:                       SQL Server Replication
  Status:                        Failed: see logs for details
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred for a dependency of the feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x84BB0001
  Error description:             Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
  Error help link:               http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=11.0.5058.0&EvtType=0x48BB60BC%400xBB814387&EvtType=0x48BB60BC%400xBB814387

  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

  Feature:                       SQL Writer
  Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

Scenario specific rules:

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20161114_145357\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading through many more articles and posts online, I could not get it working with any of those options. I have seen similar comments from other people who were not satisfied with those answers either. Hence I can definitely say that there is an inherent problem somewhere causing you a lot of pain if you were to have a corrupt or bad SQL Server Developer/Express installation in the first place. For now, I am satisfied with the following and thought of posting it here in case it helps someone. **Its a bit weird that after changing the SQL Server installation path to a different folder (in my case I changed it to "D:\SQL\Microsoft SQL Server") the Database engine installs without any issues**.

Couple of points to remember if you were to encounter a similar issue:
 1. If you were to see an "unauthorized operation" or similar error during installation, please run the tool ProcessMonitor (Sysinternal/Microsoft) and inspect the trace after filtering for the SQL Server Engine installer process.
[Unauthorized operation while installing SQL Server 2012 Express/Developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOwu3.png) 
 2. I have seen that the service account that the "SQL Server Agent" and the "SQL Server Database engine" uses is probably created on the fly and this may not have enough access rights to the registry. I am not very sure on this one, however its worth a look at changing it to some other account (say LocalService) if nothing helps.

3. In the development environment, You could try giving full permission to the
   registry key in question. In my case it was being owned by the "System" account and could not grant permissions easily. I rebooted Windows 10 into safe mode and gave the required permissions and then rebooted back to the normal mode.

[Registry Permissions, user accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhWSY.png)