# Error while installing SQL Server Express 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 Express on Windows 7 and I always get this error message at the last step of the installation:

> The following error has occurred:
>
> Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
>
> Click 'Retry' to retry the failed action, or click 'Cancel' to cancel this action and continue setup.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: are you running as administrator?

Comment: yes I run the setup.exe file as an administrator, but the error still appear

Comment: is the event-log telling you something?

Comment: Please have a look into this [SO-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40710841/7564182).